# Showing the Gaussian shift theorem for bivariate case

Tags: correlation, distribution, statistical-finance

I was reading about the Gaussian shift theorem in "An Introduction to Exotic Option Pricing" by Peter Buchen and came across a question that I can't seem to figure. In the book, he uses F(Z) (a measurable scalar function of Z, Z being Gaussian rv with a normal variate) but the function doesn't appear in the question and rather just uses Z1 and Z2.

[image]

where 1D is the univariate Gaussian distribution and
GST is the Gaussian shift theorem

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Gaussian Shift Theorem says that, for a standard Gaussian random variable $Z$, constant $c$, and function $F$, we have the expectation
\begin{align*}
E\left(e^{cZ} F(Z) \right) = e^{\frac{1}{2} c^2}E\big(F(Z+c) \big).
\end{align*}
Given the decomposition of $Z_2=\rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z$, where $Z$ is independent of $Z_1$, 
\begin{align*}
E\left(Z_1 e^{a Z_2} \right) &= E\left(Z_1 e^{a \rho Z_1 + a \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z } \right)\\
&=E\left(Z_1 e^{a \rho Z_1}\right) E\left(e^{a \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z } \right).
\end{align*}
Now, you can apply the Gaussian Shift Theorem to compute each of them.

Comment: My attempt gave me:
e^(0.5a^2)E(Z1+aρ)e^(0.5(a^2-a^2ρ^2))E(a√(1−ρ^2) +Z)
= a^2e^(0.5a^2)

Should E(a√(1−ρ^2) +Z) not have been there to begin with if E(e^(a√(1−ρ^2)Z)) is treated as the expectation of a constant?

Comment: My bad, my attempt gave me √(1−ρ^2)a^2pe^(0.5a^2) not a^2e^(0.5a^2), and that I assumed E(Z1) and E(Z) would both equal 1 if they follow the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: assuming $c= a \rho$, for the first one, and $a=a\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$, for the second one.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't completely follow.